# Xamarin MulticastLock Acquiring doesn't allow multicast

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, multicast

I am using Xamarin to create an Android application. This app must, among other things, receive a multicast stream. The server is sending fine, but my app is not receiving properly. If I acquire the multicast lock, which is what my research seems say is all I need to do, I can see I have the lock, but the app still does not receive the data.

```
var wifiManager = var wifiManager = (WifiManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);
// Acquire the lock
if (wifiManager != null)
{
    // _lock is a private member WifiManager.MulticastLock _lock
    _lock = wifiManager.CreateMulticastLock("PiEar");

    if (_lock != null)
    {
        _lock.Acquire();
    } 
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Could not acquire multicast lock"); // Does not print, meaning I do acquire the lock (and _lock.IsHeld() returns true)
    }
} 
else 
{
    Debug.WriteLine("WifiManager is null"); // Does not print, meaning it is not null
}
```

If I then use a different app, [MSniffer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andriell.multicast_sniffer), it not only receives the data, but allows my app to do so as well. Am I doing something wrong with attempting to acquire the lock?

Also, I have the following permissions:

- ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
- CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
- ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
- INTERNET
- CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE

### Edit 1: More info

The `.cs` page's code in question is below. `_receivedMessages` is a `ListView`, allowing me to visually see received data. The above code is what is run on `line 2` below. The only code in the dependency service is the code acquiring the lock.

```
var service = DependencyService.Get<IMulticastLock>();
service.Acquire();
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("224.0.0.69"), 6666);
            var multicast = new UdpClient(endpoint);
            while (true)
            {

                var multicastBytes = await multicast.ReceiveAsync();
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(multicastBytes.Buffer);
                Debug.WriteLine($"Received: {message}");
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    _receivedMessages.Add(message);
                });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: As i know,  acquring a MulticastLock will cause the stack to receive packets addressed to multicast addresses. How do you use this in Xamarin.Forms? If you use this specific android API, have you try to use this via dependency service?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT Good question, I have the code above, I am only acquiring the lock through a dependency service. See edit 1 for code, but when I use a different app in the background that uses multicast, then the code I have works, leading me to believe that I am just not acquiring the lock correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check the IPAddress and ports.
2. You could try to use the code below about how to create and configure UdpClient.

   ```
   public class MulticastUdpClient
   {
    UdpClient _udpclient;
    int _port;
    IPAddress _multicastIPaddress;
    IPAddress _localIPaddress;
    IPEndPoint _localEndPoint;
    IPEndPoint _remoteEndPoint;

    public MulticastUdpClient(IPAddress multicastIPaddress, int port, IPAddress localIPaddress = null)
    {
        // Store params
        _multicastIPaddress = multicastIPaddress;
        _port = port;
        _localIPaddress = localIPaddress;
        if (localIPaddress == null)
            _localIPaddress = IPAddress.Any;

        // Create endpoints
        _remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(_multicastIPaddress, port);
        _localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(_localIPaddress, port);

        // Create and configure UdpClient
        _udpclient = new UdpClient();
        // The following three lines allow multiple clients on the same PC
        _udpclient.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
        _udpclient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        _udpclient.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
        // Bind, Join
        _udpclient.Client.Bind(_localEndPoint);
        _udpclient.JoinMulticastGroup(_multicastIPaddress, _localIPaddress);

        // Start listening for incoming data
        _udpclient.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceivedCallback), null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Send the buffer by UDP to multicast address
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bufferToSend"></param>
    public void SendMulticast(byte[] bufferToSend)
    {
        _udpclient.Send(bufferToSend, bufferToSend.Length, _remoteEndPoint);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Callback which is called when UDP packet is received
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ar"></param>
    private void ReceivedCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // Get received data
        IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(0, 0);
        Byte[] receivedBytes = _udpclient.EndReceive(ar, ref sender);

        // fire event if defined
        if (UdpMessageReceived != null)
            UdpMessageReceived(this, new UdpMessageReceivedEventArgs() { Buffer = receivedBytes });

        // Restart listening for udp data packages
        _udpclient.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceivedCallback), null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Event handler which will be invoked when UDP message is received
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<UdpMessageReceivedEventArgs> UdpMessageReceived;

    /// <summary>
    /// Arguments for UdpMessageReceived event handler
    /// </summary>
    public class UdpMessageReceivedEventArgs: EventArgs
    {
        public byte[] Buffer {get;set;}
    }

   }
   ```

Comment: Did this even work? How did this post get voted up? There is nothing in this MulticastUdpClient code that is any different than what many people are already using, not to mention ChatGPT.  This code does NOT work on Android.